# In PHP does specifying an argument type in a subclass method where the parent method accepts any type break LSP?

Tags: php, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

If my Interface has a method:

```
doSomething($param);
```

And my class which implements this interface specifies the argument type like so:

```
doSomething(int $param) {}
```

Does this break the LSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: it is sound for a function `f2` to be a subtype of another function `f1` if `f2`'s arguments are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type) (and its return type covariant) w.r.t to those of `f1`.

Consider your example: a client of the upper `doSomething` (`f1`) assumes that it may pass any value to the function, but if the actual implementation being called is the lower `doSomething` (`f2`), an error may be raised because this implementation only accepts integers.

You might also find [this article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html) about variances in Scala interesting.

Comment: Ok so if I want to restrict different types in subclasses I'm better off having separate interfaces/parent classes?

Comment: If you want to be *sound* (i.e. avoid any possibility of runtime errors), then yes. Another option is to be unsound in general - such as Java and its covariant arrays - which enables certain use cases, but also means that users may have to perform additional runtime checks in order to detect/prevent errors. See https://medium.com/javarevisited/variance-in-java-and-scala-63af925d21dc for a discussion of Java vs. Scala.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff's answer is spot on. Covariant argument types are _very_ desirable from a modelling perspective (e.g. animals eat food; carnivores eat meat.), but permitting them can lead to run-time type errors. Eiffel is the most mainstream language that permits covariance, which tells you how rare covariance is .